# Convert Grayscale RGB Bitmap to RGBA PNG

Tags: c#

I have an RGB Bitmap with no transparency, which has a White background and Black text, which is anti-aliased to the white background.  I'd like to create a new Bitmap that will:

- Keep the Black pixels Black
- Convert White pixels to be 100% transparent
- Convert all Gray pixels to by Black but with a transparency so it appears to be the same Gray when placed on a White background (I think this would be the intensity of the color?)

The new Bitmap could be on any new background color and correctly anti-alias to that background color.

The question I found that was most silimar is: [Change background colour of an anti-aliased image using C# with anti-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967378/change-background-colour-of-an-anti-aliased-image-using-c-sharp-with-anti-aliasi). However, I'm starting with an image that has transparency defined so I thought it'd be better as a new question then as a comment on that one.

Comment: Your question is very vague and unspecific. What kind of answers do you expect, given the little you have told us about your problem/difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a 'Multiply Blend Mode' like in photoshop: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Multiply

The question you are referring to seems to show the basic logic for this. Unfortunately I can't give or find specific example code.

If you want to make the 'gray' pixels transparent, I would keep the color black and instead change the transparency of the pixels. 
For example, if you have a pixel that's 50% black, instead of using

```
ARGB(255, 128, 128, 128)
```

you can make it

```
ARGB(128, 255, 255, 255)
```

Surely there is a better 'algorithmic' way to do this (maybe also multiplying the alpha channels), and I know this is probably not the 'out of the box' code example you were expecting, but I hope this may help you to find a solution...